# Is there a way to use Docusaurus just for the /docs directory?

Tags: docusaurus

I have an existing website, and just want to use docusaurus to manage the /docs directory (e.g. published as a static site into there).  When I follow all the documentation it creates both the docs directory and separate website directory, how can I just have it render /docs when testing locally and only publish that sub-directory when doing a build of the static site?

Answer (score 10):

Found the answer in [the docs](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/docs-introduction#docs-only-mode):

> To enter docs-only mode, change [your configuration] to like this:
>
> docusaurus.config.js
>
> ```js
> module.exports = {
>   // ...
>   presets: [
>     '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
>     {
>       docs: {
>         routeBasePath: '/', // Serve the docs at the site's root
>         /* other docs plugin options */
>       },
>       blog: false, // Optional: disable the blog plugin
>       // ...
>     },
>   ],
> };
> ```